# Subject Alternative Name not added to certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to issue a new certificate using the additional attribues field within the  Windows CertSrv Web-Enrollment Client.

I added the CSR, picked the template and entered this into the attributes field:

```
SAN:dns=HOSTNAME&dns=HOSTNAME.DOMAIN.COM&ipaddress=IPADRESS
```

The request is successful but when I check the signed certificate no "Alternative Names" attribute is added to it. Am I missing something? Maybe a issue with the Template? (used a default Win 2003 level webserver template copy with some custom settings).

/edit
Also I've tried to use

```
certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:MYTEMPLATE" <Cert Request.req> -attrib "SAN:dns=HOSTNAME&dns=HOSTNAME2&ipaddress=IPADDRESS"
```

resulting in the same problem: cert gets generated, but without any SAN attribute.

/edit2 
also I've set the CA to issue SAN certificates using

```
certutil -setreg policy\EditFlags +EDITF_ATTRIBUTESUBJECTALTNAME2
```

and restarting the CA service. Still: no SANs.

Please note: using req. files and OpenSSL to generate the CSR i'm able to generate certifcates using the CA which have some SANs included. However this option is not valid in my current situation since I'm getting the CSR from an application and i'm not able to manually generate one for the application.

/edit3
**I tried using the default webserver certificate WITHOUT any changes and suddenly it worked. So now the question is: what are the template requirements to enable SAN?**

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I've just figured it out myself and thought it might help someone else.  I too have been unable to get CA to add the SAN via either the web page or the `certreq ... -attrib "SAN:DNS=<FQDN>[&DNS=<FQND2>...]..."` format.  The SAN attribute was ignored, even though the certificate was issued.

However, I found that it works with this format: `certreq -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer\nSAN:DNS=<Name1>[&DNS=<name2>...][&IPAddress=<IP1>...]" <csr filename> <cer filename>`

For example, if you have a certificate request file called HP_VC.csr and you want the subject alternative names to be vc1, vc2, vc1.domain.com, vc2.domain.com, 192.168.1.1, and 192.168.1.2 the command would be:

```
certreq -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer\nSAN:DNS=vc1&DNS=vc2&DNS=vc1.domain.com&DNS=vc2.domain.com&IPAddress=192.168.1.1&IPAddress=192.168.1.2" HP_VC.csr HP_VC.cer
```

The certificate in HP_VC.cer will contain the SAN attribute.

I'm using this for HP Virtual Connect (VC) modules, Onboard Administrators (OA) and iLOs.  It should work for any generic situation that needs a certificate with a SAN.

Comment: I can't tell you if this would work for me since as I said it just suddenly worked. However a interesting fact I found out however is that the console command NEEDS a template. But don't worry: if the request contains any specific informations the template Settings will be overwritten by the request file. The resulting certificate will state the request informations, not the template informations.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I did the same but the SAN line when you look at the certificate it does not show the SAN in the certificate at all.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer here, too, which solved the problem for me: http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2017/09/adding-san-subject-alternative-name.html

It seems by default the certificate service does not actually accept SubjectAltName input from the web form, for possibly good security reasons. As someone comments on this page - it depends on how well you trust the access controls to your cert services web console.

Comment: This appears to be a link-only answer. Please edit your question to include the relevant details from the link you provided. The subsequent paragraph is not an explanation of the link contents, just a cautionary tale about how OP's attempt doesn't work.